# Any pointers to server side pagination jQuery plugin in jsp?

Tags: jquery, jsp, pagination, server-side

I know this is something I can find very easily on google. But trust me I have put 5 hours but not able to find any code for this. I want to implement server side pagination in my application. I new to Jquery, pagination. I want to limit number of pages in pagination UI, something like [this](http://beneverard.github.io/jqPagination/).
But I don't know how should I implement it. In my application I am passing list of records that it fetched from database to jsp and jsp is just putting all those records in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [dataTables](http://datatables.net/) plugin in my last two Struts2 based projects. Among various amazing capabilities it also provides [server side pagination](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html). Here is how to implement server side code for implementing it in JSP:

- [Server side processing - JSP](http://datatables.net/development/server-side/jsp)

Comment: Hey thanks anu, i already checked datatables, thing is server side is the PHP code, i need it to be in java/J2EE. and thanks for the link to 'Server side processing-JSP' but don't know hoe this will be handled server side, how it will implement pagination. My application has pagination as well as filter. filter we have already implemented, so databaase records can be default one or filtered one that are coming from the action class.

Comment: In the given JSP code the pagination is handled using `sStart` and `sAmount` variables. Look at line #132 and 133 to understand how they are used to handle pagination.